How to edit/add text to QVideoFrame
I have a demo PyQt6 application using the QtMultimedia library to capture live video from a webcam and record it via QCamera, QMediaCaptureSession, QVideoWidget and QMediaRecorder.
I want to add some text to the frames. I believe this is possible by using the map() QVideoFrame.toImage() and unmap() functions. I want the text to be present on the QVideoWidget as well as the exported video file.
However, the resulting QImage returned by the QVideoFrame.toImage() function is always Null (using the QImage.isNull() function).
I have tried different QCameraFormat's offered by my webcam, YUYV, JPEG, NV12 etc. but it makes no difference.
I have tried the QVideoFrame.addSubtitleText() function, but that does not embed the text into the video frame, so it is not present on the exported video file.
How can I add text to a QVideoFrame?
I am using Python3.10 and PyQt6.7.1.
import os

from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtMultimedia import (
    QCamera,
    QCameraDevice,
    QMediaCaptureSession,
    QMediaDevices,
    QMediaRecorder,
    QVideoFrame,
)
from PyQt6.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QComboBox,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "my_video.mp4")


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        self.m_devices = QMediaDevices()
        self.devices_list = QComboBox()
        [
            self.devices_list.addItem(str(d.description()), d)
            for d in self.m_devices.videoInputs()
        ]
        self.devices_list.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.devices_list.activated.connect(
            lambda idx: self.set_camera(self.devices_list.itemData(idx))
        )
        self.main_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Select Camera"))
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.devices_list)

        self.start_btn = QPushButton("Start Recording")
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start_recording)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton("Stop Recording")
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_recording)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.stop_btn)

        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        self.video_sink = self.video_widget.videoSink()
        self.video_sink.videoFrameChanged.connect(self.on_video_frame)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.video_widget, 1)

        self.m_recorder = QMediaRecorder()
        self.m_recorder.recorderStateChanged.connect(lambda state: print(state))
        self.m_recorder.setOutputLocation(QUrl.fromLocalFile(video_path))
        self.m_recorder.errorOccurred.connect(lambda error, error_str: print(error_str))

        self.m_capture_session = QMediaCaptureSession()
        self.m_capture_session.setVideoSink(self.video_sink)
        self.m_capture_session.setRecorder(self.m_recorder)
        # self.capture_session.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

        self.camera = QCamera(QCameraDevice())

        self.show()
        self.resize(800, 600)

    def set_camera(self, camera: QCameraDevice):
        self.camera = QCamera(camera)
        self.m_capture_session.setCamera(self.camera)
        self.camera.start()

    def start_recording(self):
        self.m_recorder.record()

    def stop_recording(self):
        self.m_recorder.stop()

    @pyqtSlot(QVideoFrame)
    def on_video_frame(self, frame: QVideoFrame) -> None:
        """ """
        if not frame.isValid():
            return

        if not frame.map(QVideoFrame.MapMode.ReadOnly):
            return

        img = frame.toImage()

        ### edit QImage here ###

        print(f"Frame received (null={img.isNull()})")

        frame.unmap()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    main = Main()
    app.exec()



In your title you assert that the videoFrameChanged signal stops firing, but in your post you say that the resulting image is always null, which you couldn't know if the signal wasn't actually firing. So, is the signal emitted or not? I've never used media capture, so I may be wrong, but if you need to write on the video frame (so that it's shown on the video widget), you must open the frame in write mode. It will also help to know more about your environment, most importantly the OS and Qt (not PyQt) version.

Unrelated: using list comprehensions to do looped calls is normally pointless and actually less efficient, as it actually creates a list of values that are not being really used (see this related post). Most of the times, a normal for loop syntax will be better both for performance and readability. In your case, using it for addItem() is pointless, and its readability is way worse than a more practical and instantly recognizable for loop.

Apologies, the title was left over from another queastion I was going to ask but no longer need to - I've corrected it, the videoFrameChanged signal is working correctly. I am using Windows 11 and Qt 6.7 (the PyQt version matches the underlying Qt version).
Interesting point regarding list comprehensions, I agree that a regular for loop in this case would be considered more readable.

I have tried changing the MapMode, ReadOnly results in a non-Null QImage, whereas WriteOnly and ReadWrite result in a Null QImage. From the documentation it appears ReadWrite mode is required to apply modified frame data. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvideoframe.html#MapMode-enum

Unfortunately, as said, I've no experience with Qt media capture, and, to be honest, I'm not even sure you can directly do what you want. Also, even after its Qt6 reintroduction, the QtMultimedia module has been subject of lots of changes that are still ongoing, and the documentation is also often incomplete or inaccurate for that reason. My suggestion would be to ask on the official Qt forums and ask first if what you want to do can be achieved with the "object chain" you propose.
